# Get Html using Sokcet via Proxy

Tags: java, c#, sockets, websocket

I have a code in Java that allows getting HTML from WEB site via Proxy Server:

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new example().request("stackoverflow.com", "/enterprise", 443);//It is just example
    }

public void request(String host, String path, int port) throws Exception {
    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    Socket tunnel = new Socket("myproxyserver.com", 22225);//It is just example
    String auth = "Admin:PASS";//It is just example
    String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());
    OutputStream os = tunnel.getOutputStream();
    String msg = "CONNECT "+host+":"+port+" HTTP/1.1\n"
        +"Proxy-Authorization: Basic "+base64+"\n"
        +"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
        +"\r\n\r\n";
    byte b[] = msg.getBytes("ASCII7");
    os.write(b);
    os.flush();
    int lines = 0;
    InputStream is = tunnel.getInputStream();
    while (lines<2) {
        int i = is.read();
        if (i<0)
            throw new IOException("Unexpected EOF from proxy");
        if (i=='\n')
            ++lines;
        else if (i!='\r')
            lines = 0;
    }
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(tunnel, host, port, true);
    socket.startHandshake();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
    out.println("GET "+path+" HTTP/1.0");
    out.println();
    out.flush();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
    out.close();
    socket.close();
    tunnel.close();
    }
}
```

I want to do the same with C#. I found the following code but it is not working:

```
 string server = "myproxyserver.com";
        int port = 22225;
        string host = "https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise";
        var base64 = "bHVtLWN1c4RvbWVyLWhs4zM4HTI2N2M2LXpvbmUtc3RhdGljEmU3ZWN5Y3ByY2U2YQ==";
        string request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + ":" + port
       + "\r\nProxy-Authorization: Basic " + base64 + "\n"
       + "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
       + "\r\n\r\n";
        Byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
        Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];

        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

        var ipe = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], port);

        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            socket.Connect(ipe);

            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection established");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection failed");
                return;
            }

            socket.Send(requestBytes, requestBytes.Length, 0);

            int bytes = 0;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            do
            {
                bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes));
            }
            while (bytes > 0);


            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

It is returning string but I am expecting HTML:

```
   Connection established
HTTP/1.1 403 No Protocol
X-Luminati-Error: No Protocol
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2020 03:26:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

How can I fix this?
**UPDATE**
I wanted to do it through WebClient but it is throwing time out exception:

```
 var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        client.Proxy = new WebProxy("myproxyserver:22225");
        client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Admin", "Password");
        Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise"));
```

However, it is working fine in HTTP web sites. Also, I tried to do this with the postman. It is also throwing time out exception. When I open the console I can see this error:

> Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET

Comment: Why do you need to do this, you could make the request with a HttpClient in a few lines of code and get all this information in a usable way

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes, you are right. The reason is: proxy service is blocking sending the request to https WEB sites in my location. They said I should do it via socket and sent me some examples in Java and NodeJs.

Comment: What is it actually returning. Can yo update the question? Also you might want to put what you just said into the question as well

Comment: @TheGeneral I updated the code. Request with Socket is returning request header. Look at above of UPDATE

Comment: Great!, also what does the socket give you back?

Comment: @TheGeneral Connection established
HTTP/1.1 403 No Protocol
X-Luminati-Error: No Protocol
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2020 03:26:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: @ahh ok, i see. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218863/discussion-between-dilshod-k-and-thegeneral).

Comment: @TheGeneral Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I can't look at this now, but I will when I get a chance

Comment: @TheGeneral I couldn't find the issue. Can you help me, please?